# Getting HTML code of Child Component from Parent Component in Angular 14

Tags: angular

in my Angular project, I want to access the html code in the child component from the parent component, I apply pdf conversion in the parent component, but I want to get the design of this pdf from the child component.

Comment: Do you want to access this statically once when something in the parent component is triggered or do you want to be notified in the parent component once the design is changed in the child component?

Comment: I have an exportToPdf function in my Parent Component, when this function is triggered I want to get the html data of my child component child. exportToPdf code inside my function;    var html = htmlToPdfmake(htmlTemplate);
  const documentDefinition = { content: html };

  const pdfDocGenerator = pdfMake.createPdf(documentDefinition);
  pdfDocGenerator.download("create.pdf")        htmlTemplate here I want to assign the child's html to the html variable

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you need here is the `@ViewChild` decorator in order to reference your child component from inside your typescript logic in your parent component.

If the data you need is a variable in your child component, you can use it like this:

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent, {static: true})
child!: ChildComponent;

//...
//use it like this:
console.log(child.yourNeededVariable);
```

If you on the other hand need to read the actual HTML content of your child, you can do the following:

```
@ViewChild(ChildComponent, {static: true})
child!: ElementRef;

//...
//use it like this:
console.log(this.child.nativeElement.innerHTML);
```

Keep in mind that {static: true} is an option to adopt in the case the ElementRef you're trying to access is declared statically (no *ngif whose default value is false or dynamic loading is allowed) and you need it already in ngOnInit lifecycle method

Comment: static: true is helpful if the component is not dynamically loaded or if it doesn't have a *ngif whose default is false, so pay attention using it

Comment: That's correct. I should have added that to my answer. From use-case perspective it sounded like this child component is indeed static, therefore I just assumed it. Feel free to edit my answer and add the missing information. I will gladly accept your proposal :)